# What's the best way to extract a list of i18n strings from a meteor app?

Tags: meteor, internationalization

I'm using [this i18n package](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) to internationalise my meteor app and I'm looking for a tool to automatically create a i18n json file from the strings surrounded by "{{_" and "}}" in my meteor folder.

Do you know a script for this or alternatively is there a way to do it using Sublime Text / Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use grep to find all strings, copy to a new file, and then format accordingly.

```
grep -r "{{_.*}}" . > output.txt
```

I can't remember, but you might have to escape the curly braces in the search string.

Unfortunately, not all versions of grep support recursive searching, and some use different switches, so if you're running into problems, check your man pages.